# How does a Bingo Caller App generate numbers 1-75?

Tags: random, numbers, google-apps-marketplace

There's a free Bingo Caller App that generates numbers 1-75 every time you start a new game. It also generates numbers when offline. How does it do that?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: (1) Create a list containing all the numbers from 1 to 75. (2) Shuffle the list randomly.

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation then coming back with a more specific question

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestion:

It's not possible to say for sure exactly how the numbers are generated as we don't know *which* app you mean nor do we have access to its source code, but generating numbers can be done simply like so:

#### Code:

**JavaScript example:**

```js
// Generates numbers 1-75 every time you start a game:
function setUpNewGame() {
  var bingoNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <=75; i++) {
    bingoNumbers.push(i);
  }
  return bingoNumbers;
}

// Picks a random number from the available numbers each round:
function pickNumber(availableNumbers) {
  var currentPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (availableNumbers.length + 1));
  console.log(availableNumbers[currentPick] + " has just been drawn!");
  availableNumbers = removeBall(availableNumbers, currentPick);
  return availableNumbers;
}

// Removes the last picked number from the available numbers:
function removeBall(availableNumbers, position) {  
  const i = availableNumbers.indexOf(position);
  if (i > -1) {
    availableNumbers.splice((i + 1), 1);
  }
  return availableNumbers;
}

// Plays the game:
function playTheGame() {
  var numbers = setUpNewGame();
  numbers = pickNumber(numbers); // Logs "X has just been drawn"
  
  // hasSomeoneWon() is an function which checks bingo cards
  // of all players. returns true if a card has 6 matches
  // returns false if no card has yet won
  while (!hasSomeoneWon()) {
    numbers = pickNumber(numbers)
  }
  console.log("We have a winner!")
  return;
}
```